# Which are the most complete DirectX game or technical demo with source available

Tags: directx, open-source

I have found plenty of games with source for OpenGl, but so far I haven't found anything like that for DirectX. There are plenty of examples in the SDK, but they are very basic and usually they just expose one very specific aspect of the API at a time.
So I am wondering which are the best or most complete DirectX games with source available these days.

EDIT

I am making a small study about the differences in the final output across different GPUs. I want to have games in DirectX and OpenGL. To remove any differences caused by non-determinism, like thread scheduling and timing information. I already have done it for Doom 3 which is a great example for OpenGL. I would like to have something in DirectX to perform similar tests with, and I was hoping I could find something better than the simple demos included in the SDK.

Comment: there is no need to find a game. just check latest opensource Game-Engines. they'll do fine by themselves. for example take a look at irrlicht.

Comment: Thanks, that does help a lot, but I would like to have a game already built for that engine. Perhaps if I explain a little more of what I want to do, I can make the point for wanting a game. I will go ahead and edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a comparison of GPU data, it would make sense having the same game that can run on both DirectX and OpenGL. A lot of commercial games do this, but not a lot of source is available.

One suggestion I can make is to have a look at the [Darwinia and Multiwinia source code](http://store.introversion.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=66). It's not exactly free, but I believe it makes use of both DirectX and OpenGL and it's not the most expensive thing in the world.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, if there was such a game that has a back end implemented in both which happened to be open source it would be the ultimate solution to my problem. 
It seems to support DirectX 9.0c and if it runs on Mac I assume it must be using OpenGl as well.
I will definitely take a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

UDK has many complex demos available

Comment: cloudraven is asking for examples using the DirectX API.